# Customize Android base interface

Tags: android

Which files i need edit and learn to customize the android desktop, such: change main bar, turn off slider bar, turn-off desktop slide, and put a menu in desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom launcher. Look at this for some guidance: http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/wiki/CompleteGuideToADW

Comment: @devdevdev you can select this as the answer by clicking that big check next to the vote count.